# R transformation as.POSIXct to Date substracts one day

Tags: r, posixct

If I have POSIXct date in R, for example

```
as.POSIXct("2023-10-11 00:02:00")
"2023-10-11 00:02:00 CEST"
```

I get unexpected output if I transfer it to Date

```
as.Date(as.POSIXct("2023-10-11 00:02:00"))
"2023-10-10"
```

Have to say I have no idea why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify `tz` (timezone) in `as.Date()` according to your needs and you are good to go:

```
as.Date(as.POSIXct("2023-10-11 00:02:00"), tz = "Europe/Berlin")
[1] "2023-10-11"
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of optional arguments in as.Date() from the help file:

```
## S3 method for class 'POSIXct'
as.Date(x, tz = "UTC", ...)
```

Here, the timezone (tz) argument is likely what is causing the difference in your two examples.

In your first case: "2023-10-11 00:02:00 CEST" shows 2am in CEST timezone.

Seeing from the help file above, the default tz argument in as.Date is UTC.  If you specify Central European Time (CET) then your results should be the same

```
as.Date(as.POSIXct("2023-10-11 00:02:00"),tz="CET")
```